# Why does my for-loop not work with set binterval borders?

Tags: java, for-loop

My task is to create a multidimensional array that is seperated in n pieces from a range of min to max.

So if the range is 0 til 90 and it is devided in 6 pieces it should look like this

```
int[][] array = {   {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14},
                        {15, 16, 17, 18, . . ., 29},
                        {. . .},
                        {. . .},
                        {. . .},
                        {. . ., 90}
                        }
```

```
    public class H {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int min = 0;
        int max = 90;
        int n = 6;


        // 90 / 6 = 15
        int elementsInBin = (max - min) / n; //15
        int[][] bin = new int[n][elementsInBin];
        
        //n = 6
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){

            int leftBound = elementsInBin * i;
            int rightBound = (elementsInBin * i) + (elementsInBin-1);

            int span = rightBound - leftBound;

            for(int j = leftBound; j < span; j++){
                System.out.print(bin[i][j]);
                
                
            }  
        }  
    }
```

so the first loop is n long because these are the rows and im defining the left and right border of the interval of the row.
the next for loop starts with the left bound 0 and with the right bound 14 and it counts up the span.
then in the new next loop the left border is at 15 and the right border is at 15 + 15 -1 so 29 and the next for-loop should count from the new left border (15) to 29.

but my output is always

00000000000000

im not getting what im doing wrong.

Comment: Im not getting an outofbound exception and the leftbounds are correct (o, 15, 30...). so in the second loop it should start from 0 and count up. i think im printing it out the wrong way? or storing it the wrong way?

Comment: omg yes this is right!

Comment: Suggestion: Seeing it was resolved without an answer, delete the question.